# Can i install two different constraints for the same UIView based on a size class?

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder, autolayout, size-classes

I started using size classes in Xcode 6, and i'm trying to set constraints for the same view, depending on the device size.

Let's say I have a UIView and I need these constraints to be applied:

- For 4" display (iPhone 5):
  The leading and trailing spaces from superview to be 5px from each side.
- For iPhone 6 (5.5") The leading and trailing spaces to be 20px.

This image illustrates what i'm looking for:

[image: Here's a image that explain it a little more]

Is it possible to do with size classes?
i started working for wCompact x hAny by setting the margin to 5px in that layout. And than switched to wCompact x hRegular by setting the margin of that view to 20px.

But it seems to be 20px in all devices (including 4.7"), like its not considering the first constraint.

What am i missing here? is it even possible to do on the same view in size classes?

p.s Using Xcode 6, xib file (no storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like perfect centre x.

You could install a center x constraint on the subview against the superview's center x.

You'll just need to fix set the width of the subview.

If that doesn't suit, set the constants of the leading and trailing constraints manually in code either in awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad. Then call layoutIfNeeded: on the view.

Comment: It is centered, but the width is different and the padding is not the same. I know I can do it by code, I was wondering if there is a way to do it with size classes

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this with size classes.

Comment: I edited the question, im sorry but i made a mistake- i need the first constraint to be applied to iphone 5 dimensions (4") and not to 4.7". maybe that makes it doable now? (one constraint to Compact | Any, and one for Compact | Regular)

Comment: All iPhone devices in portrait use wCompact/hRegular so you size classes won't be the solution here.  This [link](http://www.jessesquires.com/adaptive-user-interfaces/) has a great visual for the size classes each device uses (and yes I realize it's there when you select the size class, but I don't think it's as clear as it could be).

Comment: Awesome link there @KurtAnderson